# _valuable name(underscore + valuable name) javascript

Tags: javascript, getter, setter

I am currently learning JavaScript, and have a question about _variable name.

Firstly, what is the relationship between valuable name, and same valuable name with underscore? I am using this._title in getter and setter to get value from title, but I do not understand why _title can be used without declaring, and also when console this._title, it is able to show the value of title.

```
const movies = [];

const addMovieHandler = () => {
    const title = document.getElementById('title').value;

    const newMovie = {
        info: {
            set title(val) {
                if(val.trim() === ''){
                    this._title = 'DEFAULT';
                    return;
                }
                this._title = val;
                console.log(this)// shows the object of new movie
                console.log(val)// show value of title
                console.log(this._title)// also show value of title
            },
            get title() {
                return this._title.toUpperCase();
            }

        }
    };

    newMovie.info.title = title;//setter
    console.log(newMovie.info.title);//getter


    movies.push(newMovie);

};
```

Thank you for your help!

Nagisa

Comment: The `_` character can be used in any name; it's no more special than `x` or `B`.

Comment: It's arbitrary. It's a coding convention to prefix a variable with `_` to indicate that it is an internal variable not meant to be directly accessed by outside things.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for replying. but I did not declare _title with const or let. why I can use it without declaring?

Comment: You are conflating variables and properties, they are distinct: `const foo` declares a constant named 'foo', `this.foo` means the property 'foo' of whatever object `this` points to. In you code `this` is automatically given to you by the runtime when you call a method, and like any JS object you can add and change properties of it at will. The underscore is not relevant to your question as it's just a character in the name and is not given special treatment.

Comment: javascript does not require you to declare variables, but it is useful for enforcing scope of the variable. In your case, `this` is already implicitly scoped, and you have code that creates `_title` in that scope (IOW a property of `this`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stepping back a bit, traditionally:

```
title = 'foo'; // assigns value 'foo' to title (set action)
console.log(title); // references title (get action)
```

You work directly with `title`, assigning a value to it directly, and when you reference it, js returns the value of it.

The concept of `get` and `set` methods is that you can add a proxy layer to the variable to write your own code to define what happens when you assign something to `title` (set) or reference it (get).  This is most commonly used to add logic for default values or validate/scrub/format values.

So in your code, `title` and `_title` are two distinct variables that are not directly/intrinsically tied together, except by your own conventions set within `title`'s `set` and `get` methods.

And within `set` and `get`, you do whatever you want. In this case, you are using an "internal" variable `_title` to hold the actual value. This can be named anything you want, but by convention, many people use the same variable name as the public one, but with a `_` prefix. You don't even need to have one at all; it just depends on what your goal is.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much, I think I understand it. I just started learning setter and getter, and your explanation for them helped me to understand them too. 
Thank you for your help!